# Disable autoplay for HD trailers in QuickTime X

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, quicktime

Since QuickTime X came out, whenever I watch HD trailers from [Apple](http://www.apple.com/trailers), they automatically begin playing as soon as possible. Is there a hidden preference to disable that? My question may be similar to [a previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/41881/snow-leopard-turn-off-embedded-quicktime-auto-play) on QuickTime X autoplay for embedded videos. I'm assuming it's a `defaults write` thing…

Answer (score 2):

Open up terminal. Run the following command:

```
defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX MGPlayMovieOnOpen 0
```

Run this to turn it back on:

```
defaults write com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX MGPlayMovieOnOpen 1
```

You might need to restart Quicktime and/or the whole system for it to grab the new defaults.

Take a look at [this](http://megabytecomp.com/apps.aspx) Preferance Pane too, it will make changes to QuicktimeX easier until they implement preferences in the app itself.

Comment: Took me a bit of time to respond because I was testing it out a few different times. Doesn't work, either with the Preference Pane or with the command. Trailers from Apple autoplay as soon as they're loaded enough. +1 anyway for the Preference Pane. Didn't know about that.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it appears that the autoplay preference applies to files that I open from my computer, and not trailers that load from Apple's website. Hmm.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken to double striking the space bar as soon as the QuickTime window opens. This starts and then quickly stops playback, disengaging autoplay while the trailer buffers. It isn't a proper solution, but as good of a workaround as I've been able to come up with.